# How to call Facades method from boot method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

In laravel 6 app I created facade app/Facades/MyFuncsClass.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MyFuncsClass extends Facade{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'MyFuncsClass'; }
}
```

But I got error :

> ```
> "message": "Non-static method App\\Helpers\\MyFuncsClass::debToFile() should not be called
> ```
>
> statically",

calling it from boot method:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($task) {
        $hostel_image_image_path= Task::getTaskImagePath($task->id, $task->image);
        MyFuncsClass::debToFile(print_r($hostel_image_image_path, true), '-9 $hostel_image_image_path::');
        ...
```

Is there is a way to escape this error  and run MyFuncsClass::debToFile in boot method ?

**MODIFIED** :
Sure I registered my facade in config/app.php, 'providers' block :

```
...
App\Providers\MyFuncsClassProvider::class,
```

file app/Http/Helpers/MyFuncsClass.php has a lot of public methods, with heading:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MyFuncsClass {

    public $concat_str_max_length = 50;
    public $m_concat_str_add_chars = '...';

    public function debToFile($contents, string $descr_text = '', bool $is_sql = false, string $file_name = '')
    {
        try {
        ...
```

and in app/Providers/MyFuncsClassProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class MyFuncsClassProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('MyFuncsClass', function()
        {
            return new \App\Helpers\MyFuncsClass;

        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Actually I can call \MyFuncsClass::debToFile( ok from not static methods, like control actions, but I have the error 
calling from static boot method...

**MODIFIED # 2** :
With real time facades https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades#real-time-facades defintions
I tried

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;
use App\Http\Helpers\MyFuncsClassContainer; // Alias for my helper class
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;

class Task extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($task) {
            $hostel_image_image_path= Task::getTaskImagePath($task->id, $task->image);


            \Log::info( '-9 $hostel_image_image_path::' );
            \Log::info( print_r($hostel_image_image_path, true) );
            $myFuncsClassCore = factory(MyFuncsClassContainer::class)->create();
            $myFuncsClassCore->debToFile(' debToFile string REDSA');
```

Bur anywat I got error :

```
 Cannot declare class App\Helpers\MyFuncsClassContainer, because the name is already in use {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException
```

I tried a way to rename my helper class to “MyFuncsClassContainer”, supposing
having the same name for helper and facade could raise error, but failed

If there is a way to fix this error ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you registered your facade in app.php config file?

Comment: Are you registering the class with a service provider? Also, please can you add the code you have for `App\Helpers\MyFuncsClass` class to your question.

Comment: Please, look MODIFIED block

Comment: Hello, any ideas how to call facade methods from static boot method ? facade seems so good thing, but I encountered this problem . I used traits before, but moved to facade as I considered them modern laravel decision for common app methods...

Comment: Please, look MODIFIED # 2 block